# Creating a function that operates different string cleaning operations

Tags: python, string, pandas, function

I built a function that performs multiple cleaning operations, but when I run it on an object column, I get the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str' error. Why is that?

```
news = {'Text':['bNikeb invests in shoes', 'bAdidasb invests in t-shirts', 'dog drank water'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian']}
news_df = pd.DataFrame(news)

def string_cleaner(x):
    x = x.str.strip()
    x = x.str.replace('.', '')
    x = x.str.replace(' ', '')

news_df['clean'] = news_df['Text'].apply(string_cleaner)
```

Comment: You can use :  news_df['clean'] = news_df['Text'].transform(string_cleaner)

Comment: if you have multiple replacements, join them with a `|` i,e `pat = '|'.join([',', ' ')]` then `df['text'].replace(pat, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
news = {'Text':['bNikeb invests in shoes', 'bAdidasb invests in t-shirts', 'dog drank water'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian']}
news_df = pd.DataFrame(news)

def string_cleaner(x):
    x = x.strip()
    x = x.replace('.', '')
    x = x.replace(' ', '')
    return x

news_df['clean'] = news_df['Text'].apply(string_cleaner)
```

`apply` is used to apply a function on a pandas Series objects, the final return type is inferred from the return type of the applied function. So, you can think of passing a list of values to a function one at a time to transform those values, in your case you are sending a list of string to clean each string.

As, x is a string, the operations you're applying (strip, replace) works directly, there's no .str operation on python strings. So, it gives an error. There is a str function which is used this way str(x) to cast another python type to a string.

Comment: I had tried that, but it returns me all none values, can you check is the same for you?

Comment: Make sure to return `x` from `string_cleaner`

Comment: oh I see why that was returning no results, thanks!

Comment: Yes, the string_cleaner must return the formatted string.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why using `.str.` is wrong here (ie what is `.apply` doing). Code-only answers don't really teach

Comment: added an explanation.